# Группировка view по ширине

Tags: android, java, разметка, view

Есть массив view, c различной шириной. Как сделать что-то подобное? Может, есть готовые решения?

[image]

Comment: Ничего не понял. Но есть weight, что позволяет ширину в процентах задавать.

Comment: Поправил вопрос.

Comment: https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть стандартный [GridLayout (support v7)](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout.html).
И была статья на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/191842/).